# how to get native stream video resolution in roku/scenegraph?

Tags: roku, brightscript

Is it possible in screen graph to get native stream resolution? or at least its aspect ratio? The Video node is performing automatic scaling padding it vertically or horizontally - I need to know the video size without padding.

Thank you in advance for your feedback.

Answer (score -1):

The [Roku Video Player Node](https://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/Video) does not have an interface that provides the native resolution of the video stream.

One way to solve this is to provide the video information to your application alongside the video. So if you are hosting a list of video streams, also include the video resolution as part of the metadata.

Example JSON:

```
{
  "videos": [
    {
      "title": "My Show",
      "url": "https://example.com/video.m3u8",
      "width": 1920,
      "height": 1080,
      "format": "hls"
    }
  ]
}
```

In general video resolution is not important for UI layout purposes. Most applications will play the video back full screen, or as part of a pre-defined rectangle in the UI.